# Smalltalk - Getting the value of a string

Tags: smalltalk

I'm trying to find the value of a string. E.g.,:

```
'abc' == 6  (1+2+3)
```

But I'm getting an error on the '+ element' section below:

```
MessageNotUnderstood: Character>>adaptToNumber:andSend:
```

Can someone give me a hand?

```
wordValue: inString
    |value|
    inString asUppercase.

    value := (inString do: [ :ch | inString inject: (ch asciiValue- 64) into: [ :sum :element | sum + element ]]) asInteger.
    ^value.
```

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with smalltalk, but `str asUppercase inject:0 into:[:sum :ch | sum + ch asciiValue - 64]` worked for me. Not sure what you're trying to do with the `do:`, but it looks like it's not necessary. Perhaps you misunderstood 'inject'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you want to be doing the conversion from character to integer *inside* your loop
You also don't need the outer do:

```
wordValue: aString
  ^aString inject: 0 into: [ :sum :ch | sum + (ch asUppercase asciiValue - 64)]
```

That's all there is to it - inject 0 into the block to start with (as that's your starting sum), then each time round, the block will evaluate to the sum plus the "value" of the current character.

Also, in your version, it looks like you were trying to uppercase the string - but the statement

```
inString asUppercase.
```

Does nothing.  Or rather, it returns a *new* uppercase version of the string, which you are then not storing anywhere.  It doesn't modify inString itself (the 'as' prefix on the message provides a hint to that, as would a past-tense message name).
Rather than uppercasing the entire string first, I added the 'asUppercase' message send to the individual characters, as that way we only have to iterate over the String once.

Comment: Strings are not immutable Symbols are. You can e.g. alter an string by using #at:put:. But you can't change the receiver of message.

Comment: Ahh, very true, I was thinking of Java. I'll fix my answer.